# R distance between potential clients

Tags: r, merge

I have a data table with firms and another one with banks. I have managed to produce the longitude and latitude for each city of each bank and each firm. What I would like to do is to find for each firm the average distance between the firm and banks.

For example, let us assume I have the following datasets (I actually have more than 400 banks and several thousand firms) :

```
Data_firm <- data.frame(
  Firm = c("A", "B"),
  Postal_firm = c("20246", "67720"),
  Longfirm = c("9.2","7.8"),
  Latfirm = c("42.6", "48.7")
  )

Data_bank <- data.frame(
  Bank = c("AB", "AC"),
  Postal_bank = c("50670", "88290"),
  Longbank = c("-1.2","6.8"),
  Latbank = c("48.7", "48.0"),
  Assets = c("100", "200"))
```

I would like to add a column to Data_firm with the average distance (I calculate them with distance harvestine) between the firm and all banks in the system and another with the average distance weighted by bank size (but my issue is readlly with the first step)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(geosphere)

Data_firm <- data.frame(
  Firm = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Postal_firm = c("20246", "67720", "77720"),
  Longfirm = c("9.2","7.8", "8.1"),
  Latfirm = c("42.6", "48.7", "50")
)

Data_bank <- data.frame(
  Bank = c("AB", "AC"),
  Postal_bank = c("50670", "88290"),
  Longbank = c("-1.2","6.8"),
  Latbank = c("48.7", "48.0"),
  Assets = c("100", "200"))

# There are 2 banks and 3 firms

Data_firm %>% 
  inner_join(Data_bank, by=character()) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with(c("Lat","Long")), as.numeric)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dist = distm(c(Longbank, Latbank), c(Longfirm, Latfirm),
    fun = distHaversine))

#>   Firm Postal_firm Longfirm Latfirm Bank Postal_bank Longbank Latbank Assets
#> 1    A       20246      9.2    42.6   AB       50670     -1.2    48.7    100
#> 2    A       20246      9.2    42.6   AC       88290      6.8    48.0    200
#> 3    B       67720      7.8    48.7   AB       50670     -1.2    48.7    100
#> 4    B       67720      7.8    48.7   AC       88290      6.8    48.0    200
#> 5    C       77720      8.1    50.0   AB       50670     -1.2    48.7    100
#> 6    C       77720      8.1    50.0   AC       88290      6.8    48.0    200
#>        dist
#> 1 1054789.9
#> 2  629728.5
#> 3  660855.4
#> 4  107446.8
#> 5  689276.5
#> 6  242027.5
```

Comment: This solution does not work if you don't have the same number of bank and firms right though ?

Comment: Thanks, @Nicolas, for your comment. It should work, but you can try it out.

Comment: The edited solution works with more firms than banks, @Nicolas.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Smith it is working !

Comment: You are welcome, @Nicolas !

Answer (score 0):

here is a data.table/geosphere approach

```
library(data.table)
library(geosphere)
setDT(Data_firm);setDT(Data_bank)
#create data.table of all combinations of bank and firm
ans <- CJ(firm = Data_firm$Firm,bank = Data_bank$Bank)
# join in the coordinates
ans[Data_firm, `:=`(lon_f = i.Longfirm, lat_f = i.Latfirm), on = .(firm = Firm)]
ans[Data_bank, `:=`(lon_b = i.Longbank, lat_b = i.Latbank, assets = i.Assets), on = .(bank = Bank)]
# set coordinates to numeric
cols <- grep("lat|lon|ass", names(ans), value = TRUE)
ans[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = cols]
# calculate rowwise distance between firm and bank
ans[, firm_to_bank := distHaversine(matrix(c(lon_f, lat_f), ncol = 2),
                                    matrix(c(lon_b, lat_b), ncol = 2))]
#    firm bank lon_f lat_f lon_b lat_b assets firm_to_bank
# 1:    A   AB   9.2  42.6  -1.2  48.7    100    1054789.9
# 2:    A   AC   9.2  42.6   6.8  48.0    200     629728.5
# 3:    B   AB   7.8  48.7  -1.2  48.7    100     660855.4
# 4:    B   AC   7.8  48.7   6.8  48.0    200     107446.8

# calculate average distance to bank by firm
ans[, avg_dist_to_bank := mean(firm_to_bank), by = .(firm)]
ans[, wavg_dist_to_bank := weighted.mean(firm_to_bank, assets), by = .(firm)]
#    firm bank lon_f lat_f lon_b lat_b assets firm_to_bank avg_dist_to_bank wavg_dist_to_bank
# 1:    A   AB   9.2  42.6  -1.2  48.7    100    1054789.9         842259.2          771415.6
# 2:    A   AC   9.2  42.6   6.8  48.0    200     629728.5         842259.2          771415.6
# 3:    B   AB   7.8  48.7  -1.2  48.7    100     660855.4         384151.1          291916.3
# 4:    B   AC   7.8  48.7   6.8  48.0    200     107446.8         384151.1          291916.3
```

Comment: It is working very well thanks @Wimpel